# How do I set the country that I want to publish to only Singapore only?

Tags: ios, swift

I couldn't find the settings on itunesconnect that will set Singapore as the only country that I want this app to be published at.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to itunes connect and look for pricing and availability. After you choose price, edit your availability territories.